# VHDL process sensitivity list

Tags: vhdl

In my testbench i set reset=1 and then reset=0 after 1 ns
In the simulation, `err_count <= std_logic_vector(err_count_int);` does not execute, does anyone know why?
`reset_out <= '1';` is also executed

````
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity controller is
    port(
            enable : in std_logic:='0';
            reset: in std_logic:='0';
            clk : in std_logic;
            eds: in std_logic:='0';
            ecs: out std_logic:='0';
            reset_out: out std_logic:='0';
            en_pipeline: out std_logic:='0';
            err_count: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
        );
end controller;

architecture beh of controller is

    signal err_count_int: unsigned(4 downto 0);
    signal increment: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= "00001";

begin
    process(reset) begin
        if reset = '1' then 
            err_count_int <= to_unsigned (0, err_count_int'length);
            err_count <= std_logic_vector(err_count_int);
            reset_out <= '1';
        elsif reset = '0' then
            reset_out <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
    
    -- process(clk) begin
        -- if enable = '1' and rising_edge(clk) then
            -- en_pipeline <= '1';
            -- err_count_int <= err_count_int + unsigned(increment);
            -- err_count <= std_logic_vector(err_count_int);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk) AND eds = '1' then
            -- err_count_int <= err_count_int + 1;
            -- err_count <= std_logic_vector(err_count_int);
            -- ecs <= '1';
        -- end if;
    -- end process;
    
end beh;




```
````

Comment: Note that there is an `all` keyword that should be supported by all newer simulators that would eliminate this problem.

Comment: Does the sensitivity list mean that only operations on those signals in the sensivity list is possible upon any changes to the sensitivity list?

Comment: Or does it simply mean when any signal in the sensitivity list changes, all statement in the process are evaluated and executed?

Comment: The sensitivity list tells the simulator which signal changes trigger a new evaluation of the process.

Comment: The thing to note here is that although this is how simulation works, it is not necessarily how a synthesized design will work. Using the "all" keyword is the safest option but potentially could slow down certain simulations.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing err_count_int in your sensitivity list. Basically, a sensitivity list says "only perform calculations (in the simulation) when one of these signals changes".

Therefore, reset changes to 1 and you essentially simultaneously set err_count_int, err_count, and reset_out. But, the updated version of err_count_int isn't ready yet so I'm assuming you are getting undefined output for err_count. reset_out gets set correctly because the constant '1' is always available for assignment.

If you need further explanation, please also post the testbench and your simulation results.

Comment: But why when im using process(clk) begin with exact same assignment statements it works?

Comment: @MarkHenderson, could you edit your question to include a simulation output and testbench? Making that change, you're telling the simulator to perform calculations based on a signal that is not part of the process. This will lead to mismatches between hardware and simulation and should not be done. The simulation calculation will be updated every rising/falling edge of clk, so I could see err_count being correct after a rising and falling edge.